# Microsoft Graph API Forbiden

Tags: asp.net, .net, api, graph, microsoft-graph-api

```
Imports Microsoft.Graph
Imports Azure.Identity

Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Dim onlineMeeting = New OnlineMeeting With {
                            .StartDateTime = DateTimeOffset.Parse("2022-04-23T21:33:30.8546353+00:00"),
                            .EndDateTime = DateTimeOffset.Parse("2022-04-23T22:03:30.8566356+00:00"),
                            .Subject = "Application Token Meeting",
                            .Participants = New MeetingParticipants With {
                                            .Organizer = New MeetingParticipantInfo With {
                                                            .Identity = New IdentitySet With {
                                                                            .User = New Identity With {
                                                                                .Id = "ba525532-764a-4aa1-8103-066beca0f5a8"
                                                                                                      }
                                                                            }
                                                            }
                                            }
                            }
        Dim testing As Task(Of OnlineMeeting) = createMeeting(onlineMeeting)
        Console.WriteLine(testing.Status.ToString)
        Console.ReadKey()
    End Sub

    Public Async Function createMeeting(onlineMeeting As OnlineMeeting) As Task(Of OnlineMeeting)
        Dim createMeetings As OnlineMeeting = Nothing
      
        Try
            Dim clientId As String = "XXXXXXXXX"
            Dim clientSecret As String = "XXXXXXXXXXXXX"
            Dim tenantId As String = "XXXXXXXXXXX"

            Dim options = New TokenCredentialOptions With
                {
                    .AuthorityHost = AzureAuthorityHosts.AzurePublicCloud
                }

            Dim ClientSecretCredential = New ClientSecretCredential(tenantId, clientId, clientSecret, options)
            Dim graphClient As GraphServiceClient = New GraphServiceClient(ClientSecretCredential)

            createMeetings = Await graphClient.Communications.OnlineMeetings.Request().AddAsync(onlineMeeting)

        Catch ex As ServiceException
            Console.WriteLine(ex.RawResponseBody)
        End Try

        Return createMeetings
    End Function

End Module
```

When i execute this i get :

WaitingForActivation
{"error":{"code":"Forbidden","message":"","innerError":{"request-id":"XXXXX","date":"2021-08-27T11:38:30","client-request-id":"XXXXXXXX"}}}

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

This normally means there is no permission to perform the action.

- Check you are including the relavent scope when authenticating against graph. In this case it is 'OnlineMeetings.ReadWrite' for delegated permissions and 'OnlineMeetings.ReadWrite.All' for application permissions
- If using delegated permissions check the delegated user has permission to perform this action, if they can't do it manually you can't do it through graph.
- If using application permissions make sure you have created an appropriate application access policy as described in the blue note here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-post-onlinemeetings?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

> - Administrators must create an application access policy and grant it to a user, authorizing the app configured in the policy to create an online meeting on behalf of that user (user ID specified in the request path).